# unable to scroll a container div element on chrome (Mobile Version)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have a pop up like `div` (say parentDiv) which has a child `div` (say containerDiv) that contains a set of `div` elements and is scrollable on desktop chrome.

```
<div id="parentDiv" style="position: absolute; top: 100px;">
  <div id="containerDiv" style="overflow: auto; position: relative; height: 150px;">
       <div>List 1</div> <!--Child div elements-->
       <div>List 2</div>
       <div>List 3</div>
       <div>List 4</div>
  </div>
</div
```

Surprisingly, i'm able to scroll it on chrome on desktop, but unable to scroll on chrome on my Tablet device.

Please point out whats wrong here.

Comment: There's no scrolling on either browsers...

Comment: This works... http://jsfiddle.net/7aaecq6h/2/

Comment: @A. R.: your code works perfectly on my android chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using:

```
overflow-y:scroll
```

instead?